# Generate adjacent pair permutations where each side of the pair can only be used once

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have overlapping adjacent pairings (1:2) (2:3) (3:4) (4:5) (7:8)  ..   ..

I want to identify all the permutations, but each side of the pair can only be used once within a permutation, and I want to know the unused values.

ie.
(1:2) (3:4) (7:8)  unused: 5
(2:3) (4:5) (7:8)  unused: 1
(1:2) (4:5) (7:8)  unused: 3

Thanks in advance for suggestions and thoughts.

Some actual pair lists I'm working with are

list1 = [(427, 3434), (614, 2445), (840, 614), (910, 3939), (1065, 4314), (1347, 2616), (2445, 427), (2616, 3901), (2749, 1065), (3403, 910), (3434, 1347), (3659, 1411), (3901, 3684), (3939, 2638), (4203, 3403), (4314, 840)]

list2 = [(1218, 134), (3344, 1218), (3683, 3344), (2055, 3683), (2709, 2055)]

Comment: This is not really clear. Could you edit the question in order to explain things a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick program I threw together to solve this.  It's probably not the most efficient way to go about this, but it gets the job done.

```
l = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]  # replace with whatever your full list is
import itertools
for perm in itertools.permutations(l,len(l) / 2):
    pair_list = []
    for pair in perm:
        if pair[0] in itertools.chain(*(i for i in pair_list)) \
        or pair[1] in itertools.chain(*(i for i in pair_list)):
            break
        pair_list.append(pair)
    if len(pair_list) == len(l) / 2:
        unused = []
        for n in itertools.chain(*(i for i in l)):
            if n not in itertools.chain(*(i for i in pair_list)) and n not in unused:
                unused.append(n)
        print pair_list,'unused:',unused
```

Also, are you sure you want to identify all the permutations?  To get your exact output, I would need to replace `itertools.permutations` with `itertools.combinations`.

Here is the output I get using `itertools.permutations`:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)] unused: [5]
[(1, 2), (4, 5)] unused: [3]
[(2, 3), (4, 5)] unused: [1]
[(3, 4), (1, 2)] unused: [5]
[(4, 5), (1, 2)] unused: [3]
[(4, 5), (2, 3)] unused: [1]
```

Whereas what I get using `itertools.combinations`:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)] unused: [5]
[(1, 2), (4, 5)] unused: [3]
[(2, 3), (4, 5)] unused: [1]
```

**Edit:**  Ok, it got a bit tougher with this new revision.  What I do now is find all the subgroups within the larger list where the pairs are all adjacent to one another.  I find the combinations for each of the subgroups, then put them all back together with an `itertools.product` at the end.  Also, in my test case, I added an extra pair (8,9) to the end to make sure that everything worked for multiple groups.  Here's the code:

```
l = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(7,8),(8,9)]
import itertools,math

## Create sublists for each set of adjacent pairs
l.sort(lambda x,y:cmp(x[0],y[0]))
newl = []
subl = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if subl == []:
        subl.append(l[i])
    else:
        if l[i][0] == subl[-1][1]:
            subl.append(l[i])
        else:
            newl.append(subl)
            subl = [l[i]]
newl.append(subl)
pair_lists = []

## Find all combinations for each sublist
for subl in newl:
    cur_pair_list = []
    for perm in itertools.combinations(subl,int(math.ceil(len(subl) / 2.0))):
        pair_list = []
        for pair in perm:
            if pair[0] in itertools.chain(*pair_list) \
            or pair[1] in itertools.chain(*pair_list):
                break
            pair_list.append(pair)
        if len(pair_list) == int(math.ceil(len(subl) / 2.0)):
            cur_pair_list.append(pair_list)
    pair_lists.append(cur_pair_list)

## Combine combinations for each sublist and determine unused for each combination
final_list = list(list(itertools.chain(*i)) for i in itertools.product(*pair_lists))
for subl in final_list:
    unused = []
    for n in itertools.chain(*l):
        if n not in itertools.chain(*subl) and n not in unused:
            unused.append(n)
    print subl,'unused:',unused
```

And here's the output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (7, 8)] unused: [5, 9]
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (8, 9)] unused: [5, 7]
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8)] unused: [3, 9]
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (8, 9)] unused: [3, 7]
[(2, 3), (4, 5), (7, 8)] unused: [1, 9]
[(2, 3), (4, 5), (8, 9)] unused: [1, 7]
```

**Edit #2:**
So here, then only new thing I had to do was change the way that the list was sorted.  All the code below the comment `## Find all combinations for each sublist` can stay the same.

Here's the new code that goes above that comment:

```
l = [(427, 3434), (614, 2445), (840, 614), (910, 3939), (1065, 4314), (1347, 2616), (2445, 427), (2616, 3901), (2749, 1065), (3403, 910), (3434, 1347), (3659, 1411), (3901, 3684), (3939, 2638), (4203, 3403), (4314, 840)]
import itertools,math


def sort(l):
    l = list(l)
    newl = []
    subl = []
    i = l[0]
    while len(l) > 0:
        subl.append(i)
        l.remove(i)
        k = None
        for j in l:
            if j[0] == i[1]:
                    k = j
                    break
        if k:
            i = k
        else:
            newl.append(subl)
            subl = []
            if len(l) > 0:
                i = l[0]
    i = 0
    while i < len(newl):
        j = 0
        while j < len(newl):
            if newl[j][-1][1] == newl[i][0][0]:
                for k in newl[j][::-1]:
                    newl[i].insert(0,k)
                newl.pop(j)
                continue
            j += 1
        i += 1

    return newl

pair_lists = []
newl = sort(l)
```

Here's the output I get when I run this on your new list:

```
[(2749, 1065), (4314, 840), (614, 2445), (427, 3434), (1347, 2616), (3901, 3684), (4203, 3403), (910, 3939), (3659, 1411)] unused: [2638]
[(2749, 1065), (4314, 840), (614, 2445), (427, 3434), (1347, 2616), (3901, 3684), (4203, 3403), (3939, 2638), (3659, 1411)] unused: [910]
[(2749, 1065), (4314, 840), (614, 2445), (427, 3434), (1347, 2616), (3901, 3684), (3403, 910), (3939, 2638), (3659, 1411)] unused: [4203]
```

Comment: I think this does the trick, the first run on my data has indicated that some of my left right pairings are off.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, not all pairs necessarily overlap, and they are reported as an unused pair. eg change the last pair to (6,7)

Comment: Can you edit the expected output for if you had the pairs (1:2) (2:3) (3:4) (6:7) so I have a better idea of what it is that you want?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, really appreciate it, plugging in my actual list is only giving one combination. Think my example data is too simplified.  This is an actual pair list I'm working with   [(427, 3434), (614, 2445), (840, 614), (910, 3939), (1065, 4314), (1347, 2616), (2445, 427), (2616, 3901), (2749, 1065), (3403, 910), (3434, 1347), (3659, 1411), (3901, 3684), (3939, 2638), (4203, 3403), (4314, 840)]

Comment: Ok, I had previously thought that all the pairings were simply of the form `(n,n + 1)`, so I was sorting the data based on the first value in each list in order to split it up into groups.  Let me see what I can do for this kind of data.

Comment: Added in a new sorting method.

Comment: This isn't enough combinations. Take the sorted list (newl) - [[(2749, 1065), (1065, 4314), (4314, 840), (840, 614), (614, 2445), (2445, 427), (427, 3434), (3434, 1347), (1347, 2616), (2616, 3901), (3901, 3684)], [(4203, 3403), (3403, 910), (910, 3939), (3939, 2638)], [(3659, 1411)]] if newl[0][1] pair (1065, 4314) is used, we would expect to see 2749 from newl[0][0] as an unused value.

Comment: There is an even number of pairs inside the first sorted sublist.  The algorithm tries to include as many pairs as possible.  If there were an odd number of pairs within that sublist, many more combinations would be produced.  Try adding an additional pair beginning with 3684 to the original list and look at the output for that.

Comment: I see what's going on now, and can run with this. Thanks!